# How to find the layout of the plots?

Tags: geometry, dissection

A peasant had a square garden of $100 × 100$ meters divided into $100$ equal square plots. In the testament, he left to each of his $7$ male grandchildren a connected region of $10$ plots, forming each of the  $7$ batches the same figure. He also left to each of his $3$ female grandchildren a connected region of $10$ plots, and each of the three regions had the same figure, but that figure was different from the boys' one. Moreover, the girl's regions didn't touch two to two, that is, a girl's plot couldn't be contiguos to another girl's one. Find the layout.

Two mirror-symmetrical figures are considered equal.

I don't know how to approach this problem, and I wanted to know if there are special strategies to get started.

I found this exercise in a question from Yahoo Answers that did not have any correct answer. I tried to answer it but I couldn't. It was in Spanish language:
https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20151205035648AAm4F9l

Comment: Thank you for passing along a fun spatial puzzle! Looks like a good candidate for a [`dissection`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dissection) tag while seeing how long this takes to  solve but in the meanwhile the puzzle statement probably should mention where this puzzle came from.

Comment: Does "The three girls' grounds were not contiguous" mean that *no two* touch or that they don't *all three touch one another*? And when the boys' plots are described as "contiguous" does it mean that each one is a connected region, or that in some fashion they touch one another? (Clearly they can't all pairwise touch.)

Comment: having hard time to understand the question :(

Comment: Also asked at [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429965/how-to-find-the-layout-of-the-plots)

Comment: For both boys and girls, their inherited territory is a connected region of $10$ plots. For a girl, her territory cannot touch the another girl's territory, but two or more boys' territories can.

Comment: I found this exercise in a question from Yahoo Answers that did not have any correct answer. I tried to answer it but I couldn't. It was in Spanish language, and there the asker did not specify the origin either. Should I put this information in the question or the link to the other site?

Comment: As the source is a Yahoo site, it is probably safe to link it within the question itself, regardless of language. (Others may have a more informed opinion.) The safest option is to mention the source within the question and also add a comment that contains the link.

Comment: Okay, it's ready.

Comment: Yes, I use "plot" as a synonym of "parcel". I made an edit to the question and maybe it will be understood better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I might have misunderstood something but I don't see why the following dissection wouldn't work

> [image]
>
> This solution can also be quite easily guessed from the fact that $2+5=7$ and $2\cdot 5 = 10$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough proof but

> I believe there is no solution to this unique problem.

Here is an attempt:

> [image]

Oranges are girls' plot, and whatever connected shape you choose and whereever you put girls' plot, there is no way to put boys' plot.

Let's change girls' plot a bit:

> [image]

So again the same problem, 3 nonconnected same plot ruin the rest of the other shapes since it is mainly required girls and boys's plot shapes to be different. So I believe

> Whatever shape you choose for girls' or boys' plot, you cannot find a proper layout because of the given properties. It is also possible to put this into a code for girls and boys shapes to see there is no answer. Because there are limited shapes for boys and girls and there are limited places to put them all.